# Can I move a software RAID5 array from one system to another system?

Tags: software-raid

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on both systems. They reside on the same computer. Initially I had the system running with the OS and GRUB installed on the RAID volume (3 disks).
Next I wanted to test something and I added a new drive to the system which showed as sdd when all 4 disks where present
To avoid any problems I disconnected the power from the RAID drives and I installed Ubuntu on the new drive (now sda).

Since my tests were OK I would like to now bring back to life the old RAID volume and use it just for storage and eventually a backup if the new drive ever dies.

To recap:
-new drive -will run the OS
-old RAID volume will have OS and GRUB but I will not use it to boot from it unless the new drive dies. In such event I will simply change the BIOS settings and instruct the PC to boot from RAID

Two questions:
-will this work ?
-if I mount the RAID in the new OS will that add any info the the RAID that will make it unusable if I ever need to go back to the old config? I am thinking about disk IDs, signatures or anything like this that the new OS might add to the disk ... I know that Windows used to sign the disks but not sure how that works in Linux. I know that the drives have some UIDs but I am not sure if those are changed if you move/mount the drive under a new system

Comment: `mdadm --assemble --scan` - see http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/203073/28334. Simply assembling an array in a different environment will not render it unusable in the original one. As long as you are not doing changes to the layout or the partitioning, you should be safe.

Comment: Yes that the way to do it but I am asking about consequences, if there are any... for going back and forth between booting from the new disk and booting from the RAID itself (if needed)

Comment: No, there should not be any consequences for booting into the old OS, it would be treated like any other dual-boot scenario.

Comment: This will probably be a dual boot via BIOS.  Reading this article tells me that each disk will have its' own GPT and GUID and that does not change as long as you do not format the disk.  https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/730440-using-the-new-guid-partition-table-in-linux-good-bye-ancient-mbr-   Thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can move Linux software RAID volumes to other systems.

As @the-wabbit suggest in the comments the `mdadm --assemble --scan` should assemble it for you.

If that doesn't work you will probably need to examine the current superblock of one of the members of the RAID volume to figure out the correct things to put in your mdadm.conf.

Unless you did something weird, nothing should break automatically simply by attaching them to your system, and booting your new OS, and once you are booted with them connected you can use `mdadm --examine /dev/sdxn`, or `mdadm --examine --scan`.

Comment: I did the above md0 was recognized and I mounted that manually. Do I need to mdadm scan every time ? I am ok with leaving md0 unmounted if that is safer for my data.
On the other hand it might be healthier to have the drives scanned by Linux from tome to time. What do you recommend ? How do I automatically mount this at boot time? Do I have to edit the mdamd.conf file ?

Comment: The lines displayed by `mdadm --examine --scan` can be placed in your `mdadm.conf`.  You may need to regenerate your initial ramdisk image for this to be used during the system boot.

Comment: Apparently mdadm took care of that when I run the --assemble --scan command. Now every time when I boot the system /dev.md0 seems to be available and it is in mdadm.conf already.
Now I am just debating whether it is a good idea to keep it unmounted or not. What can go wrong if it is not mouted but listed as /dev/md0 ?